# FK Columns not saved, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I try to insert some FK in db, but the value for that column is null.
I tried to use create(), but there I got multiple value as null, not sure why.

```
// Here I store value in LkpLocation if value is not in db
$lkp_location = new LkpLocation();

if(!is_null($request->lkp_location_text)){
    $exists = false;

    if($lkp_location->where('text', 'ILIKE', $request->lkp_location_text)->count() > 0){
        $exists = true;
    }
    if ($exists) {
        $lkp_location_id = $lkp_location->where('text', 'ILIKE', $request->lkp_location_text)->pluck('id')[0];
    }else{
        $lkp_location->fill([
            'text' => $request->lkp_location_text,
        ])->save();
        $lastInsertedId = $lkp_location->id;
        $lkp_location_id = $lastInsertedId;
    }
}
dump($lkp_location_id); // here I have the last ID

// Here I store values in Person table
$person = new Person();
$person->fill([
    //columns
    'lkp_location_id' => $lkp_location_id,
    //columns
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Eloquent models protect against [mass-assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment) by default. Before using `create` or `fill` methods, you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on your models:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LkpLocation extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        //list other fillable columns here
    ];
}
```

```php
class Person extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'lkp_location_id',
        //list other fillable columns here
    ];
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot, to assign in Person model. Thank you!